# Function in R: multi arguments is not permitted

Tags: r, function, dplyr

Im trying to create a function for my manager that quantifies the quality of the soil depending on their microorganisms. i would uploud the name of the different soils microbia species and then i would get an aproximation of the total quality, The final result depends on the type of the soil, and there are four categories.  So far this is what I have done (changed the species to a, b , c, d and e so it is easier to follow)

```
soil_index <-function(comm, Type) {
  comm$score <- case_when(comm[,1]=="a" ~ 4, 
                               comm[,1]=="b" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="c" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="d" ~ 5, 
                               comm[,1]=="e"~ 3,
                               TRUE ~ NA_real_ )
                               
index <- sum(comm$score)
CR<- case_when(Type=="T01" ~ 4,
              Type=="T02" ~ 9,
              Type=="T03" ~ 6,
              Type=="T04" ~ 3,
              TRUE ~ NA_real_)
EQR<- index/CR
return(index, EQR)}
```

The final result would be the sum of the points and the sum of the of the points divided by the referenced condiction (CR). When I run this I get the error message: *Error in return(index, EQR):
multi-argument returns are not permitted*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A single object can only be `return`ed.  But, we make a single element by wrapping it in a `list` which would also make sure that the object types are maintained.  It may be also useful to have a named list, so that we can extract by name as well (`$index`, `$EQR`)

```
soil_index <-function(comm, Type) {
  comm$score <- case_when(comm[,1]=="a" ~ 4, 
                               comm[,1]=="b" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="c" ~ 4,
                               comm[,1]=="d" ~ 5, 
                               comm[,1]=="e"~ 3,
                               TRUE ~ NA_real_ )
                               
index <- sum(comm$score)
CR<- case_when(Type=="T01" ~ 4,
              Type=="T02" ~ 9,
              Type=="T03" ~ 6,
              Type=="T04" ~ 3,
              TRUE ~ NA_real_)
EQR<- index/CR
return(list(index = index, EQR = EQR))
}
```

-testing

```
out <- soil_index(dat, Type)
out$index
out$EQR
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thatk you so much. And how can i specify which one is the index and which one is the EQR since suing your response I just get the two values toqether?

Comment: @Pablo I updated the solution - i.e. return a named list by creating list as `list(index = index, EQR = EQR)` and then extract with either `$index` or `[["index"]]`